# Заполнить свойство объекта через цикл

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, как заполнить свойство значениями из ассоциативного массива?
Из PHP файла получаю массив через JSON.
С помощью JS принимаю его.

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  dataType : 'json', // Тип данных, который ожидаем получить
  url: '../php/popular_model.php', // url where to submit the request
  success : function(result) {
    var barChart = new Chart(popCanvas, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [result[0].title],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Population',
          data: [result[0].visits],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
          ]
        }]
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
  }
})
```

Нужно data, где result[0].visits заполнить остальными значениями, то есть result[1], result[2] и так, пока в массиве есть данные. Делаю это для построения графика.
Подскажите, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Не очень понятно в чем проблема. То есть у вас есть массив в котором объекты с полями `title` и `visits` и вам надо все `visits` объединить в один массив и вывести на графике? Просто судя по `labels: [result[0].title]` вам все же нужны несколько графиков, а не один общий и .... ну в общем требуются пояснения.

Comment: Мне нужен один график, где будет столько столбцов, сколько существует visits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью Array.prototype.map:

```
data: {
    labels: result.map(item => item.title),
    datasets: [{
        data: result.map(item => item.visits)
    }]
}
```

Или(в зависимости от необходимой структуры):

```
data: {
    labels: result.map(item => item.title),
    /*...*/
    datasets: result.map(item => ({
        /*...*/
        data: item.visits
    }))
}
```

Comment: Ваш первый вариант сработал) Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Видимо как-то так, но все равно не понятно почему берется `title` от нулевого значения, а значения объединяются.

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  dataType : 'json', // Тип данных, который ожидаем получить
  url: '../php/popular_model.php', // url where to submit the request
  success : function(result) {
    var barChart = new Chart(popCanvas, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [result[0].title],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Population',
          data: result.reduce((prev, cur) => prev.concat(cur.visits), []),
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
          ]
        }]
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
  }
});
```

Comment: В смысле почему от нулевого? Я же получаю в JSON массив. А массивы нумеруются с 0. Получаю первую модель в массиве

Comment: @Андрей, так если вы берете `title` от нулевого значения, значит (по логике) должны и выводить значения принадлежащие объекту из которого вы брали `title`, тогда ваш вариант - то что написал @Igor в комметариях к вопросу, но вы все же хотите общий график из всех точек и тогда логика чутка страдает.

Comment: А, я вас понял. Это просто для примера) На деле там будет совсем другое)